# How can I run a Make recipe within another Make recipe with a loop?

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
run_experiment1:
    python some_file.py \
        --data_file /somewhere/here \
        --k ${k}

run_all_experiments:
    for k in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do \
        run_experiment1 k=$$k ; \
    done
```

When I run `make run_all_experiments` I get:

```
for k in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do \
    run_experiment1 k= ; \
done
/bin/sh: 2: run_experiment1: not found
/bin/sh: 2: run_experiment1: not found
/bin/sh: 2: run_experiment1: not found
/bin/sh: 2: run_experiment1: not found
/bin/sh: 2: run_experiment1: not found
Makefile:84: recipe for target 'run_all_experiments' failed
make: *** [run_all_experiments] Error 127
```

What I can immediately notice is that there doesn't seem to be a value being input for `k` like I'd expect, and the command's not being found. How should I go about fixing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really an antipattern. You want to structure your `Makefile` so that `make` itself is in charge.

The immediate and obvious fix is that, like the error message hints, the correct command here is `make run_experiment1`:

```
.PHONY: run_experiment1 run_all_experiments
run_experiment1:
    python some_file.py \
        --data_file /somewhere/here \
        --k $$k  # notice doubled dollar sign to escape it from make

run_all_experiments:
    for k in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do \
        $(MAKE) run_experiment1 k=$$k ; \
    done
```

However, as outlined above, I would probably refactor it to something like

```
.PHONY: run_experiment% run_all_experiments
run_experiment%:
    python some_file.py \
        --data_file /somewhere/here \
        --k $*

run_all_experiments: $(patsubst %,run_experiment%,1 2 3 4 5)
```

Tangentially, targets which do not correspond to a file with that name should be declared [.PHONY](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, what is the `.PHONY` you put at the top?

Comment: Updated with a brief explanation and a documentation link.